# Need to redirect few URLs via web.config and excluding the rest

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, web-config, sitefinity

We have a requirement for redirecting couple of webpages to different URLs of our website. For instance:

```
https://old-domain/-->https://new-domain/;
https://old-domain/promotion/campaign-->https://new-domain/;
https://old-domain/about-us-->https://new-domain/about-us/company;
https://old-domain/about-us/awards-and-recognitions-->https://new-domain/about-us/company;
https://old-domain/careers-->https://new-domain/careers/;
https://old-domain/careers/apply-for-a-job-->https://new-domain/careers/;
https://old-domain/claim-status-->https://new-domain/;
https://old-domain/contact-us-->https://new-domain/contact-us;
```

We need generic rewrite rules for the above, where

1. we either redirect to the desired destination URLs (manually hard-coding them in the rewrite rules)

or

2. add a single redirect rule for the first URL and regex expression to skip the rest (since the rest can be managed internally within the CMS but not the first)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it via IIS Rewrite Rules in the web.config (unless the client requires to be able to edit those in the UI)

I would add a rule for each Url (or maybe combine a few where possible)
They could look like this:

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect old domain" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="[www.]oldDomain.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.newDomain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
....
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Edit**: Updated the rule above so that it will cater for any page on the old domain and will redirect to the same page of the new domain.

Examples:

- [www.olddomain.com](http://www.olddomain.com) will redirect to [www.newdomain.com](http://www.newdomain.com)
- [www.olddomain.com/about-us](http://www.olddomain.com/about-us) will redirect to [www.newdomain.com/about-us](http://www.newdomain.com/about-us)

Now, you can create the /about-us page in Sitefinity and make it a redirect page and redirect to wherever you want.

Comment: Hi @Veselin Vasilev, thanks for the insights. Could you help me with this part specifically, "add a single redirect rule for the first URL and regex expression to skip the rest (since the rest can be managed internally within the CMS but not the first)"